How to style markdown elements in SwiftUI
Is it possible to customize the styling SwiftUI uses for markdown elements? Specifically I want to render links with an underline instead of the tint color, which is the default behavior.
Text("This is a [link](https://www.google.com/).")


See SwiftUI Underlined Hyperlinks and SwiftUI Text - how can I create a hyperlink and underline a weblink in a string

You could try a more generic approach using AttributedString,
for example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var testText = AttributedString()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(testText)
        }
        .onAppear {
            do {
                testText = try AttributedString(markdown: "This is a [link](https://www.google.com/).")
                guard let range = testText.range(of: "link") else {return}
                testText[range].foregroundColor = .green
                testText[range].underlineStyle = .single
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}


I believe markdown does not support this. However, you can simply achieve this using the below approach, because Text has a + operator to combine various strings
Text("This is a ")
+ Text("[link](https://www.google.com/).")
    .underline()

Output

